# polyline creation from void space click

Tags: c#, winforms, polyline

To all,

I have a problem I need to overcome. I need to be able to create a polyline based on a user interface.

See picture below:

[image]

Basically, imagine a winforms panel paint method which creates the ellipses in the image. There can be any arrangement/qty of circles of any size (but they will never overlap), and they will always be bounded by a single outer circle.

I need to get it so that when the user clicks outside of one of the circles, I am able to create a polyline which bounds the "void space" region (shown in green if the user clicks there).

I can easily work from objects that have the position and size of each circle if required.

Working in C#.NET.

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Comment: Try this: Create one or more graphicspaths. You can either add the arcs needed or subtract ellipses.

Comment: did you manage to make it work?